# python vending machine program-

Tags: python, printing

The program allows the user to enter money and select an item that outputs the price.

Towards the end, the if statements, `if purchase_choice == 1: print("************ The item costs $1.00 ************")` and the following statements after that one, is not printing in the output. Can someone help me?

Here's the code.

```
print("*********************************")
print("Welcome to Vending Machine Bravo!")
print("*********************************")
print("If you would like to make a selection, please insert the appropriate currency into the machine.")


Currency deposit 
num_5Dollars = 5.00
num_Dollars = 1.00
num_Quarters = .25
num_Dimes = .10
num_Nickels = .05
num_Pennies = .01 

print()
   print("Please enter:")
if num_5Dollars == 5.00:
   print("5.00 for $5 bills")
if num_Dollars == 1.00:
   print("1.00 for $1 bills")
if num_Quarters == .25:
   print(".25 for Quarters")
if num_Dimes == .10:
   print(".10 for dimes")
if num_Nickels == .05:
   print(".05 for nickels")
if num_Pennies == .01:
   print(".01 for pennies")

user_val = float(input())


if int(user_val) == 0:
   print("0 to cancel")

print("At any point if you wish to cancel operation or go back to last menu, please enter  0. Thank you!:")
print()
print(int(user_val))
print()
print("************ Total money in machine is: ", user_val , "************")

purchase item selection  
Skittles = {'type' '1''Price': 1.00}
Reeses = {'type' '2' 'Price': 1.19}
M_and_M = {'type' '3' 'Price': 1.50}
Chex_Mix = {'type' '4' 'Price': 0.99}
Honey_Bun = {'type' '5' 'Price': 1.99}
types = [Skittles, Reeses, M_and_M, Chex_Mix, Honey_Bun]

global type
type = [Skittles, Reeses, M_and_M, Chex_Mix, Honey_Bun]

print()
print("At any point if you wish to cancel operation or go back to last menu, please enter 0. Thank you!:")
print()

print("If you would like to purchase:")
print()
print("Skittles - type '1', (Price = $1.00)")
print("Reeses - type '2', (Price = 1.19)")
print("M_and_M - type '3', (Price = $1.50)")
print("Chex_Mix - type '4', (Price = $0.99)")
print("Honey_Bun - type '5', (Price = $1.99)")

print()
purchase_choice = input()
print("Your enter is:", purchase_choice)

if user_val == 0:
    print('Item selection stopped')

else:
    if purchase_choice == 1:
        print("************ The item costs $1.00 ************")
    if purchase_choice == 2:
        print("************ The item costs $1.19 ************")
    if purchase_choice == 3:
       print("************ The item costs $1.50 ************") [tag:tag-name]
    if purchase_choice == 4:
       print("************ The item costs $0.99 ************")
    if purchase_choice == 5:
       print("************ The item costs $1.99 ************")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the user input string to an integer.

`purchase_choice = int(input())`